# Why I get Out Of Memory in GC during deserialization when i do ng build in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, ng-build, build-pipeline

I am working on CI pipeline in my project. My project consists of Angular 14 and ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API. Currently when I run my pipeline for the below step, I get an error

> Error: javascript OOM in GC during deserialization
> ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-2147483645'.

Can I please know what this error message means, and why I am getting it? I also tried to increase the size value of the parameter till `node --max_old_space_size=64384` but I still get that error message:

> FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
> ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '134'.

Below is my yaml file till that step:

```
trigger: none

variables:
- name: solution
  value: 'MyApp.sln'
- name: buildPlatform
  value: 'Any CPU'
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'Release'
- name: "npm_config_cache"
  value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

stages:
- stage: StartAzVMAgent
  jobs:
  - job: MsHostedAgentJobStartAzVM
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Azure CLI
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: "Az-DevOps-AgentManager"
        scriptType: ps
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az --version
          az account show
          az vm start --name  MyDeployment-Agent --no-wait --resource-group MyDeployment

- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool:
      name: Default
      demands:
      - Use_for -equals klcloud
    steps:
     - task: Npm@1
       displayName: Install Node dependencies (packages)
       inputs:
         command: custom
         customCommand: install --save --legacy-peer-deps 
         workingDir: 'MyApp.WebUI\MyClientApp'
        
     - task: Npm@1
       displayName: Install Node dependencies (packages)
       inputs:
         command: custom
         customCommand: install sweetalert2 file-saver --legacy-peer-deps
         workingDir: 'MyApp.WebUI\MyClientApp'

    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: Building Client App
      inputs:
        script: node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build  --configuration production --aot --build-optimizer=true --common-chunk=true  --named-chunks=false --optimization=true --vendor-chunk=true --progress=true
        workingDirectory: 'MyApp.WebUI\MyClientApp'
```

My version details are as follows:

**{
npm: '8.19.2',
node: '16.17.1',
v8: '9.4.146.26-node.22',
uv: '1.43.0',
zlib: '1.2.11',
brotli: '1.0.9',
ares: '1.18.1',
modules: '93',
nghttp2: '1.47.0',
napi: '8',
llhttp: '6.0.9',
openssl: '1.1.1q+quic',
cldr: '41.0',
icu: '71.1',
tz: '2022a',
unicode: '14.0',
ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}**

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Finally after almost 1 week I resolved this issue by installing right version of Node.js in my build agent.
No need of increasing memory (RAM) in our build agent.

Problem:
I had installed **node-v16.17.0-x86** which is not for 64-bit processing machine.

Solution:
I then installed the right version as per my build agent configuration i.e. **node-v16.17.1-x64** which is suitable for 64-bit machine.

Thank You